# TFS and Microsoft Dynamics 365: Solution Name and Version to corresponding variable in VSTS

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-devops, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Lets say i have a solution named "Dynamics_1_2_3_4.zip".I want the Name, the versions (1,2,3,4) to store in different corresponding variable in VSTS. How do I achieve this?

```
SolutionName = Dynamics
SolutionVersionMajor = 1
SolutionVersionMinor = 2
SolutionVersionBuild = 3
SolutionVersionRevision 4
```

My goal is to increment the value on one of the Solution Version. Thanks

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As I already [answered on GitHub](https://github.com/WaelHamze/xrm-ci-framework/issues/78).
You can add a PowerShell step with something like this in it:

```
"MySolution_1_2_3_4.zip" -match "^(?<name>\w+?)_(?<major>\d+)_(?<minor>\d+)_(?<build>\d+)_(?<revision>\d+).zip$"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SolutionName;]$($matches['name'])"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SolutionVersionMajor;]$($matches['major'])"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SolutionVersionMinor;]$($matches['minor'])"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SolutionVersionBuild;]$($matches['build'])"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SolutionVersionRevision;]$($matches['revision'])"
```

After the step VSTS will have the variables available like `$(SolutionVersionBuild)`

Comment: I am new to PowerShell scripting and still learning. I was able to set the value of a variable from script and print its value. I was checking the PowerShell documentation but there is no command to get the name of the artifact (correct me here if im wrong), only the location of the artifact. I am in need of an advise on how i can get the name of the solution on my artifact and set its value to a variable. After that I will be able to pass that variable to your suggested script.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to these steps below:

1. Add PowerShell task (Type: `Inline Script`; Arguments: `-p [The folder path of file, such as $(Build.SourcesDirectory)]`;

Scripts:

```
param(
[string]$p
)
Write-Host $p
$files=Get-ChildItem -Path "$p\Dynamics*.zip"
$name=$files[0].name.Split('\')[-1]
Write-Host $name
# scripts as Michael said
```

Note: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` is the local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. For example: c:\agent_work\1\s

Comment: How can I get and set the path of the artifact file to a variable? Name of the file changes everytime (they update it in CRM) so I would like to get its path dynamically.

Comment: Using Get-ChildItem to search files, check the update of my answer.